# Group of numbers (Object) into array

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I am very new to Java and this is my first problem I can't solve on my own. How can I work with that numbers coming from that Object method? I thought of putting all the resulting numbers into an array but how? I would be so happy if someone could help me!

```
int close = 0; while(close < 301){ close++;
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(close).getCell(4));
```

Comment: Java or JavaScript? :)

Comment: Java. good that I know now in which programming language I code xD

Comment: `formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(close).getCell(4));
int array[] = Object.values(formatter);` that will not work. But I think it's clear now what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Java 8 Stream API for this task. You could create method like this:

```java
private String [] getCellValues(int start, int end, int cellIndex, Sheet sheet){
       DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(); //1
       return IntStream.range(start,end) //2
               .mapToObj(sheet::getRow) //3
               .map(row->row.getCell(cellIndex)) //4
               .map(formatter::formatCellValue) //5
               .toArray(String[]::new); //6
   }
```

Now lets speak more detailed about every numerated line of code:

1. Create new `DataFormatter`;
2. Create range of integers from start(inclusive) to end(exclusive). In your case that would be numbers 1,2,3...300;
3. Apply method `getRow()` on sheet with each number as argument and return stream of `Row` objects;
4. Apply method `getCell(4)` on every `Row` object, so you get a stream of `Cell` objects;
5. Apply `DataFormatter` method  `formatCellValue` to each cell, returning stream of `String`;
6. Collect all `Strings` to array like `String[]` (consider using `collect(collectors.toList())` cause `List` is more handy);

After all the `return` statement in line `2` returns the result. If you need to convert your `String` values to `int` or `long` you should add `.map(Integer::parseInt)` or `.map(Long::parseLong)` between lines 5 and 6 and then change 6 line respectively.

If you are more familiar with loops you could just use somethind like this:

```java
 private String[] getCellValues(int start, int end, int cellIndex, Sheet sheet) {
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        int arraySize = end - start - 1;
        String[] cellValues = new String[arraySize];
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
            Cell cell = row.getCell(cellIndex);
            String cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            cellValues[i] = cellValue;
        }
        return cellValues;
    }
```

But also consider using `List` instead of array if possible.